# How to partially apply `RegExp.test` to a string?

Tags: javascript, binding, method-call

Why doesn't this work:

```
var func = /o/.test;
func("hello");
// VM165:1 Uncaught TypeError: Method RegExp.prototype.test called on incompatible receiver undefined
//     at test (<anonymous>)
//     at <anonymous>:1:1
// (anonymous) @ VM165:1
```

But this does:

```
/o/.test("hello");
// true
```

Comment: Could you please check with my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you take a method from an Object and assign it to a variable, you need to supply a binding for `this` because the context( the Object ) is not passed along with the method.

```js
var func = /o/.test.bind(/o/);
console.log( func("hello") );
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Use `call` or `bind` Method.

```
// Call Approach
    var func = /o/.test;
    func.call(/o/, "hello")

//Bind Approach
    var func = /o/.test.bind(/o/);
    func("hello");
```

Comment: This isn't valid. It's not testing for `/o/`, it's testing with a RegExp with no defined expression, any string will return true regardless of its content.

Comment: Thanks for correcting it. My bad. partially tested my code. Thanks a lot